# Would the schematic below be considered a half wave or a full wave rectifier?

Tags: power-electronics

[image]

Would the schematic below be considered a half wave or a full wave rectifier ?

Comment: HI! So, what have you tried to figure this out? What can we help you with? (For homework-style questions, we really must know what your current understanding is, else we have no way of knowing what to explain and what you already know – hence, such questions are often closed as unclear or too broad.)

Comment: I'm new to power electronics, i've been presented with the basic topologies of full wave and half wave. This topology seems odd to me, I know what the basic difference between half and full wave.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

It is a [half wave voltage doubler,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler) also known as a Greinacher voltage multiplier.

It does turn AC into DC, but its main reason for existence is that it makes a DC voltage that is twice as high as a simple rectifier.  The down side is that it can't deliver as much current as a normal rectifier.  The current is limited by C1.

Comment: I guess Greinacher is the original discoverer, but I only knew these as Cockroft-Walton stages.  Funny how someone else gets the (popularity) credit.